# Fastest way to check object attributes in an array against multiple other arrays?

Tags: arrays, ruby, iterator

I have an array of objects, 'customers' which have lots of attributes, including `id` and `associated_road`

`associated_road` is the ID of an object within 'roads', noted below.

I have another array of objects, 'old_customer_list', which has the same attribute fields as 'customers'.

**NOTE: Some customers from 'old_customer_list' will exist in 'customers' with the same ID.**

I have one more array of objects , 'roads', which has its own attributes, different from the above, one I'll use for an example is `road_type`

**What I want to do is:**

1. Iterate through 'old_customers' using `associated_road` to check against 'roads' to find the associated `road_type` for the customer.

```
old_customers_with_road = []

old_customer_list.each do |cust|
  matched_road = roads.select { |road| road.id == cust.associated_road }
  old_customers_with_road << [cust.id, cust.associated_road, matched_road[0].road_type]
end
```

This is already slow, so if there is a clearer method of doing this, or if this part is skippable altogether, I'm all ears.

2. From this point I'd like to check the 'customers' array, with the main aim being to update the `associated_road' attribute IF:

`old_customers_with_road` contains a matched ID (`cust.id` from the old_customer_list) AND the 'roads' array has a matched `road_type` (matching `matched_road[0].road_type` from the 'old_customers_with roads' array).

I'm not sure how best to do this, avoiding nested iterations through several arrays using `any?` `each` or `select` as these arrays can have thousands of objects within.

Any pointers appreciated!

Comment: Do you have this data in a database? This would be faster in SQL

Comment: Yes, however this is part of a larger ruby script so hoping to keep it within ruby if possible

Comment: My suggestion is to make roads a hash keyed with id, so the lookup will cost constant time. The similar may also applied to other list.

Comment: Just a small point, you can use `find` instead of `select` because you only want a single record, not an array